# Needing to retain Lab category tests based on individual positive test result

Tags: sas

Hello so this is a sample of my data (There is an additional column of LBCAT =URINALYSIS for those panel of tests)

[image: Sample Data]

I've been asked to only include the panel of tests where LBNRIND is populated for any of those tests and the rest to be removed. Some subjects have multiple test results at different visit timepoints and others only have 1.I can't utilise a simple where LBNRIND ne  '' in the data step because I need the entire panel of Urinalysis tests and not just that particular test result. What would be the best approach here? I think transposing the data would be too messy but maybe putting the variables in an array/macro and utilising a do loop for those panel of tests?.

Update:I've tried this code but it doesn't keep the corresponding tests for where lb_nrind >0. If I apply the sum(lb_nrind >  '' ) the same when applying lb_nrind >  '' to the having clause

```
*proc sql; 

*create table want as 
select * from labUA 
group by ptno and day and lb_cat
having sum(lb_nrind > '') > 0   ; 

data want2;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.ptno);
set labUA;
by ptno period day hour ;
if not flag_group then flag_group = (lb_nrind > '');
end;   

do _n_ = 1 to _n_; 
set want; 
if flag_group then output;
end;   

drop flag_group; run;*
```

Comment: It's not clear what your requirements are. I can't tell if you're trying to work across rows or columns. It would be more helpful to show your data and expected output. And please post data as text not images, we can't do anything with images. You can look into CMISS() which will count the number of missing across a set of variables. `if cmiss(of lborresu--lbcat) = 0 ;` would ensure that all rows had all values of variables between lborresu and lbcat non missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SQL` `HAVING` clause to retain rows of a group meeting some aggregate condition.  In your case that group might be a `patientid, panelid` and condition at least one `LBNRIND not NULL`

Example:

Consider this example where a group of rows is to be kept only if at least one of the rows in the group meets the criteria `result7=77`

Both code blocks use the SAS feature that a logical evaluation is `1` for *true* and `0` for *false*.

**SQL**

```
data have;
  infile datalines missover;
  input id test $ parm $ result1-result10;
  datalines;
1 A P 1 2 . 9 8 7 . . . .
1 B Q 1 2 3
1 C R 4 5 6
1 D S 8 9 . . . 6 77
1 E T 1 1 1
1 F U 1 1 1
1 G V 2
2 A Z 3
2 B K 1 2 3 4 5 6 78
2 C L 4
2 D M 9
3 G N 8
4 B Q 7
4 D S 6
4 C 1 1 1 . . 5 0 77
;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select * from have
  group by id
  having sum(result7=77) > 0
  ;
```

**DOW Loop**

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if not flag_group then flag_group = (result7=77);
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if flag_group then output;
  end;

  drop flag_group;
run;
```

Comment: I added a modified version of the code. Would you be able to clarify where i am going wrong? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Your criteria evaluation can be changed from `(lb_nrind > '')`  to `(not missing(lb_nrind))`